# Get Latest on All Open Projects from TFS Server using Eclipse Plug-In

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Is there a way, in Eclipse with the TFS plug-in, to get latest from the TFS server for all open projects?  Maybe something similar to getting latest on an entire solution in Visual Studio.  Getting latest in an entire working set would be OK too, but I don't see a way to do that either.

I realize that I can do this using TFS command line utilities or by using the TFS shell integration.  This is inconvenient though.  I'd love to be able to do it in Eclipse as easily as I can in Visual Studio.  Another plug-in or something would be fine as long as it integrates cleanly with Eclipse.

I'm using "TFS plug-in for Eclipse" version "12.0.1.201403041643" against Team Foundation Server 2010.  Eclipse is Luna 4.4.  The projects are primarily Android Java projects, if that makes a difference.

Here's a shot of what I am doing now.  This works, but I have to do each project individually.  The goal is to do something like this, but only once for all open projects.

[image: TFS Client Commands]

Comment: Why can't you select all the projects, right click, and select Team > Get Latest Version?  Do you have non-TFS mapped projects in your workspace as well?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I didn't realize I could do that.  Feel kinda dumb actually.  That's better than nothing.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I did just notice that muti-selecting across working sets or if I select a closed project, Get Latest Version is not an option.  Still, better than I had.  Write it as an answer and if I don't get a better one, I'll accept it.